# django cannot read css file in static folder

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am trying to make a base.html template and inserting a css file in the header. in the page it includes all the styling by it does not do any styling when the link the other page is pressed.

I have two files extending base.html one color_choose.html the other statistics.html which have the exact same lines for linking files. color_choose.html works and it is the first page that opens when navigated and the other is statistics.html

here is the base.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="eng">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <title>ColorStore</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        {% block styles %} {%endblock%}
      </head>
      <body>
         <div id="ColorFavor">
           <div style="float: right;">
             <h2 id="title" class="page-name">Color Picker</h2>
           </div>
         </div>
         {% block navigation %}
         {% endblock %}

         {% block display %}
         {% endblock %}

         {% block modal %}
         {% endblock %}

         {% block scripts %}
         {% endblock %}
       </body>
    </html>
```

here is the urls.py in the app file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ColorPageView.as_view(), name='color'),
    path('statistics/',views.StatsPageView.as_view(), name='statistics'),
```

this is the file css is applied and is also the same text in the other file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block styles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/main.css" type="text/css">
{% endblock %}
```

And this is the part in the settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

If I am missing anything I will edit this post as soon as possible, just leave a comment for it.

Comment: By 'django cannot read' do you mean that the browser is 404ing when it tries to fetch the stylesheet? It can also be helpful to use django's static template tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a slash '/' before 'static/...'

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/main.css" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template should have {% load static %} and you should refer to the stylesheet either as /static/styles/main.css or (preferably) you should use the macro "{% static styles/main.css %}"

See the django doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files).